# Why does this complex limit exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand the following comment:

> It's not difficult to see $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[i\pi+\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)^n\right]$$ doesn't exist

I'm thinking to transform this limit to a one in $\mathbb R^2$, but I got something weird (an ordered pair raised by $n$).

Any ideas how to prove the non-existence of this complex limit?

Comment: If you want to consider this as a limit on $\mathbb{R}^2$, you need to consider the whole expression as something in $\mathbb{R}^2$ not its parts. Euler's formula should help, if you can rewrite $(3+4i)/(5i)$ as $re^\phi$ for some $r$ and $\phi$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If consider $z_n:=i\pi+\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)^n$, then $(z_n)_n\subset \mathbb{C}$ doesn't converge since 
\begin{align}
|z_{n+1}-z_n|&=\left|\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)^{n}\right|=\left|\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)^{n}\right|\cdot\left|\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)-1\right|\\
&=\left|\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)\right|^n\cdot\left|\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)-1\right|=\left|\left(\frac{3+4i}{5i}\right)-1\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{3-i}{5i}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{10}}5.
\end{align}

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm reviewing this course and there are many things I don't remember anymore. Why $|z_n|=1$ for every $n$ implies $(z_n)$ not convergent?

Comment: The answer is right, but technically you have to add that $\frac{3+4i}{5i} \neq 1 $.

Comment: Your right. I edited it.

Comment: So this is not convergent because it's not a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: "Therefore neither $(z_n)_n$ nor a subsequence of $(z_n)_n$ converge." Where is the argument showing that no subsequence converges? Actually, for every $w$ on the unit circle, there exists a subsequence $(z_{\varphi(n)})$ such that $z_{\varphi(n)}\to i\pi+w$. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Did: I already removed that part.

Comment: @user42912: Yes, It's no Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Why this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D+i%5Cpi%2B((3%2B4i)%5C(5i))%5En? thank you

Comment: @user42912 For once, WA is right, in its own lingo, since it says that the limit set is $$i\pi+e^{2i0\ \text{to}\ \pi}$$ that is, that every point $$i\pi+e^{2i t}$$ with $$0\leqslant t\leqslant\pi$$ is a limit point of the sequence $(z_n)$.

Comment: In fact, the sequence is not convergent. Wolfram Alpha maybe try to give the set of limit points instead of the limit. But I'm not absolutely sure if each point in $\{i\pi+w\in\mathbb{C}~:~|w|=1\}$ is a limit point of $(z_n)_n$ since WA also claims $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n=e^{2i~0~\text{to}~\pi}$.

Comment: You can be absolutely sure.